# C# Parse string to type known at runtime

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a file holding some of the variables of a class, and each line is a pair : *variable, value*. I'm looking for a way to load these at runtime (a-la `XmlSerializer`), using reflection.

Is there a way to parse a `string` into a `Type` known only at runtime?

The following is a wishful code sample where the last line (with the `pi.SetValue()` is not correct, because `PropertyType` is of class `Type` which does not have a generic `Parse()` method.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(settingsFileName))
{
    String  line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] configValueStrs = line.Trim().Split(seps);

        PropertyInfo pi = configurableProperties
                .Single(p => p.Name == configValueStrs[0].Trim());

        //How do I manage this?
        pi.SetValue(this, pi.PropertyType.Parse(configValueStrs[1].Trim()), null);
     }
 }
```

Since all of the relevant variables are Ints, Doubles, Strings or Booleans, as a last resort, I can Switch on the type and use the corresponding `ToType()` method, but I bet there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the static [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx)  method for that. It takes an object as its first parameter and a [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) instance you want to convert the object to. The return value is of the type you requested or null if no suitable conversion was found. This method throw 4 different exceptions, from which three are caused by the value it tries to convert. You might want to catch and handle these.

Use the function as follows in your example:

```
// Convert.ChangeType can throw if the string doesn't convert to any known type
    pi.SetValue(this
      , Convert.ChangeType(configValueStrs[1], pi.PropertyType) 
      , null);
```

Answer (score 38):

TypeConverters are the way to go. Take a look [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx) for a good example of what to do.

Nicked straight from hanselmans blog:

```
public static T GetTfromString<T>(string mystring)
{
   var foo = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
   return (T)(foo.ConvertFromInvariantString(mystring));
}
```

Comment: +1 to this as it will handle GUIDS, Convert.ChangeType will not

Comment: Good answer, but that code is rather inelegant, and in some cases you have the type at run-time, not compile-time. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70354581/184528

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `TypeConverters`, Specifically `StringConverter` can help you with this problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.stringconverter.aspx

Comment: Check this: http://chrismarinos.com/default-typeconverters-and-objects/ Also in my own experience, the default implementation can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **MethodInfo** on the property for the **Parse** method and see if the MethodInfo object is valid. Then, carry out the parse operation if valid.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I consider to be a cleaner implementation of the answer from [Scott Hanselman via Russell Troywest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626476/184528)

```
   public static object Parse(Type t, string s)
      => TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t).ConvertFromInvariantString(s);

   public static T Parse<T>(string s)
      => (T)Parse(typeof(T), s);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same task to load variables of a class, using reflection. I load key/value pair strings from a file, then I parse the values basing on corresponding key variables' definitions from my settings class.

Briefly, I use the following code (method `FieldInfo.SetValue (Object, Object)` is the key here, because it doesn't require any type conversion of the `Object` value, returned by `TypeConverter.ConvertFromString` method):

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

....

Settings settings = new Settings();   // my Settings class with variables to load
FieldInfo[] fields = settings.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Static);
....

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if (key.KeyName == field.Name)
    {
        try
        {
            field.SetValue(settings, TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(field.FieldType).ConvertFromString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, key.Value));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: The value string \"{0}\" isn't parsed!", key.Value);
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        } 
        break;
    }
}
```