# How do I parse a string to a specific object type based on Type?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using reflection to map command line arguments to public properties.  What I ended up with is a brute force method that takes a string and returns an object of a specific type.  How can I do this without creating a logic for every single C# type?  Is there a language or class feature designed to do this?  Here is what I have now.

```
private static object ParseValue(Type type, string argValue) {
   object parsedValue;
   if (type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(int?))
      parsedValue = int.Parse(argValue);
   else if (type == typeof(long) || type == typeof(long?))
      parsedValue = long.Parse(argValue);
   else if (type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(double?))
      parsedValue = double.Parse(argValue);
   else
      parsedValue = argValue;
   return parsedValue;
}
```

The calling method then uses `property.SetValue(this, parsedValue);`

Comment: [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-6.0) will cover the common cases.

Comment: Use a [library](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline) to do it for you.

Comment: This has been answered on another post, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8626476/7623490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [Convert.ChangeType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_) method.

In your case, instead of calling the ParseValue method, you can do something like this:

```
parsedValue = Convert.ChangeType(type, argValue)
```

where "type" is the type that you passed to ParseValue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with reflection you can use:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ParseValue(typeof(int), "123");
    }
    
    public static object ParseValue(Type type, string argValue)
    {
        var m = type.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[]{typeof(string)});
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var result = m.Invoke(instance, new object[]{argValue});
        Console.WriteLine("The result is: " + result.ToString());
        return result;
    }
}
```

You should check that the Type has a Parse method before to invoke it.

Check it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6dWvrM)